# How can I perform Date math within a QBO3 XSLT template?

Tags: xslt, qbo3

I am trying to develop a form using XSLT in a Quandis Business Objects domain.

I need to prepopulate a field based on the length of time between the current date and a previously recorded date.

In this use case, I would like to subtract two dates and receive the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the DateDiff function provided in the XSLTFormatting class.

```
format:dateDiff('yesterday', 'today', 'dd')
format:dateDiff('10/31/2016', '11/1/2016', 'dd')
```